# SQL Server 2012 IIF not recognized

Tags: sql-server-2012, iif

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have been trying to use the IIF function, but I'm getting the following error,

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
>   'iif' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Even with something as simple as

```
 SELECT IIF(5 > 4, 'true', 'false')
```

it fails. In fact, that exact statement gives an "Incorrect syntax near '>'." error

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any chance you might be using the **Management Studio 2012**, but you're connecting to an older version of the SQL Server engine?

Run `SELECT @@Version` and show us the output - this will show you what **engine** version you're connected to.

In my case, I get:

> Microsoft SQL Server **2008 R2** (SP2) - **10.50**.4000.0 (X64)
>   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

What do you get?!?

`IIF` **only** works if you're connected to a **2012** (v11.0) engine version!

Comment: Yep. Must be this. Also tested changing compatibility level down on a database and that doesn't cause this error.

Comment: BINGO!  That is the problem, thank you!  This is what I got Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)